# Page Controller and WebView tedious refresh

Tags: ios, uiwebview, refresh, uipagecontrol

I've implemented a Page Control in my app that enable moving in three instances of the same view with data dynamically populated.

I've tried to put in this view images and labels and everything worked fine. Now I'm trying to use a WebView, since I would like to display formatted text. To populate html I've used the following code:

```
if (currentViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    currentViewController.view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:currentViewController.view];

    NSDictionary *numberItem = [contentList objectAtIndex:page];
    [currentViewController.formattedTextView loadHTMLString:[numberItem valueForKey:@"HTMLcode"] baseURL:baseURL];
}
```

If I navigate between pages using buttons everything works well, but if I try to swipe there is a tedious refresh problem. Note that I've tried to put last line of code directly in view controller implementation, but the problem persists.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance, yassa

Comment: Searching around I've found that WebViews raise many performance issues, so this is the expected behavior. As a workaround I implemented only one web view that scrolls in vertical, instead of paging.

Answer (score 0):

Most app developers are not aware of the reading experience of WebView, escpecially on e-ink devices. Below are two threads which might be of general interest:

[Prevent unwanted flicker due to innate WebView behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561866/android-prevent-unwanted-flicker-due-to-innate-webview-behavior/8928742#8928742)

[Android with E-Ink display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238708/android-with-e-ink-display/8913501#8913501)